# GetBindingExpression returns null when I have a binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding

This is my ItemsControl code:

```
<ItemsControl Name="SearchItemsControl" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchResult, IsAsync=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Background="{StaticResource PopUpContentGradientBrush}" >
```

and yet this:

```
BindingExpression be = SearchItemsControl.GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty);
```

returns null.

Why does it return null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a high chance that you check it when the element is not loaded. To be sure you should test the code such as in a `Loaded` event handler of the window:

```
//in the scope of your window class
Loaded += (s,e) => {
  var be = SearchItemsControl
            .GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty);
  //be should not be null now.
};
```

Also be sure that your `Binding` is successful. Usually you can see the `Output` window, it will notify any Binding related error there.